# Rubik's adjacent corners exchange

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

I want to make the pattern as shown in the images
I get stuck at the last with two adjacent corners to be interchanged.
How do I do this ?
[image][image][image]

Comment: Do we have to find the hidden image to solve the puzzle?

Comment: Sorry, image was not loaded because size was more...please check now

Comment: I think this is trivially illegal due to it being a single "twist" of the 2x2x2 corner. For the cube to be valid all three sides need to be paired to their opposite or all three must be not paired with their opposite. You have red-orange paired which are opposite but the other are not opposite. If you change your color combos you should be able to solve it without an illegal corner swap.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to build a cube in a cube pattern like this.

On a 3x3 Rubik's Cube, it is not possible to switch two opposite or two adjacent corners.

---

There is another way to build a cue in a cube pattern on a 3x3.
Just follow this algorithm:
`U' L' U' F' R2 B' R F U B2 U B' L U' F U R F'`

Check out [this page](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/notation/) for some explanation on the notation.

Comment: I want to switch two adjacent corners only i was not able to do it so i had to remove the pieces and put them into place to take the picture

Comment: It was the yellow orange and green corner at the top in the first image with the adjacent corner on the left of it

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the cube within a cube pattern ?

Comment: @MovinFernandes I edited my answer. Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar pattern but the color combination is different from the image in question.

> Reference ruwix.com known as [cube in the cube](https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/rubiks-cube-patterns-algorithms/)

Algorithm

> you need to start from all color matched Rubik cube position. 
>  F L F U' R U F2 L2 U' L' B D' B' L2 U